# chown -R user:group * won't affect dot files

Tags: chown, dot-files

I noticed the command `chown -R user:group *` ran as root won't affect dot files like .htaccess, unless I specify them one by one, like `chown -R user:group .htaccess`

How to make `chown -R user:group *` effective on dot files too?

Answer (score 1):

I had to use `chown -R user:group .*` because the wildcrd in bash does not expand to dot files by default, unless the dot is explicitly specified.

That behavior may be changed with `shopt -s dotglob`, which sets the option to always includes hidden files when expanding filename patterns (known as "globbing").

Comment: Or `chown -R user:group * .*` to match both dot files and non-dot files.

Comment: Careful, that chown doesn't do what you think it does. '.*' also matches '.' and '..', so you're chowning the *parent* directory itself and everything under it, including the current directory, and all of their subdirectories. If you run it under `/home/foo`, you'll end up chowning *all of `/home`*.